# visionOS AVPlayerViewController continues to play video in the background even when window is closed

Tags: ios, swift, avplayerviewcontroller

As the title suggests, I open the video in a new window, but when I try to close it while it's playing, the window closes but the video seems to continue to play in the background. I can tell this as the audio is continuing.

Here's the code

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct VideoPlayerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var videoURL: URL
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        // Wrap AVPlayerViewController in a plain UIViewController to manage its view lifecycle more directly
        let containerViewController = UIViewController()
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
        
        // Configure the player
        playerViewController.player = player
        playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = true
        
        // Ensure the player view controller's view fits the container view
        playerViewController.view.frame = containerViewController.view.bounds
        playerViewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        
        // Add the player view controller as a child to the container view controller
        containerViewController.addChild(playerViewController)
        containerViewController.view.addSubview(playerViewController.view)
        playerViewController.didMove(toParent: containerViewController)
        
        return containerViewController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        // Perform any updates to the UI or player if necessary
    }
}




struct VideoWindow: View {
    var body: some View {
        // Ensure the video URL is correctly provided
        VideoPlayerView(videoURL: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "TimesSquare2DShort", withExtension: "mov")!)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) // Optional, based on layout needs
    }
}
```

I've tried to debugprint, and it seems that .onDisappear is not being registered even when the window is closed.